# Redirect to a specific Page through local notification tap xamarin forms

Tags: notifications, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, portable-class-library

I am creating a **Xamarin forms** app for iOS and Android, So far I have implemented the local notification in the **PCL** and I am able to schedule the notifications , my issue is that when I tap the notification, it shows the app in the background or the main page of the app , but I have to load a particular screen when the user enters by tapping on the Notification.
PS I have used *Plugin.Notification* for crossPlatform local notification

```
        TimeSpan _time = new TimeSpan(14, 43, 0);
        TimeSpan _time2 = new TimeSpan(14, 46, 0);
        DateTime date1 = date.Date + _time;
        DateTime date2 = date.Date + _time2;

        var _ = this.ScheduleNotification(1, date1);
        var __ = this.ScheduleNotification(4, date2);

 public async Task<bool> ScheduleNotification(int id,DateTime time)
    {

        Notification lLocalNoti = new Notification()
        {
            Id= id,
            Title = "DEMO APP",
            Message = $"welcome {id}",
            Vibrate = true,
            Date = time,
        };

        await CrossNotifications.Current.SetBadge(1);
        await CrossNotifications.Current.Send(lLocalNoti);
```

Any sample projects, tutorials, suggestion will be thankful

Comment: I know this post is old but I was just wondering if you found a solution?  I have the exact same scenario and can't figure out how to redirect to a page when the user clicks on the notification

Comment: Yes , I got a workaround for this issue, but I had to change my approach to resolve this issue, as I used Dependency services to schedule the notifications for both android and iOS, and in iOS used the app delegate methods to get the notification tap and in android used the intent information to get the notification tap information and handle accordingly. because using the plugin we can only find the notification tap event in iOS only ,but to implement it in android also we cannot use the same approach, as there aren't any delegate methods in android.